# Spark Streaming two action ned to be run after each other

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application whichI am working on a FileStream..the stream would have two main action which I need to call the second one exactly when the first one is finished

```
dstrea.foreachRDD(action1)
dstream.foreachRDD(action2)
```

action 1 update some information into hbase...while acton 2 read from those information so in each batch action 2 shroud be run after action1

I wanted to know how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to combine the two action in one foreachRDD function:

```
dstream.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
    action1
    action2
})
```